# Searchable input field with dropdown or search field in dropdown?

Tags: search, input, dropdown

In location input field that has a dropdown on click, is it best practice for the input field to also be a search field to filter through the dropdown results, or treat the input field more as a button and have a separate search field in the dropdown?

Option 1: input field with search function (example - 'To' field on [United](https://www.united.com/en/us))

Option 2: separate search field in dropdown (example - [Amplitude](https://images.app.goo.gl/DqMXVSxFKSAnURn78), country location)

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is for fields, where value should be selected only from the popup dropdown.

Option 1: The problem arises when the user is editing the same field again. Here, the existing field value needs to be selected and changed to search for new values. Try changing the value once one of the values is already selected.

Option 2: It always shows what is selected and what is available to select. Unless we search and select anything from the popup dropdown, the currently selected value remains visible. The focus can directly go into the search field as there is nothing to type in the field itself.

I recommend Option 2.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about best practices, but its better for me as a user to be able to search within the same field which shows the dropdown as most of the places have this model and its intuitive enough plus its also mobile friendly. Why make me do an extra click or scroll to input my filter keywords.